# "Fast" as an Adverb vs Adjective using NLTK pos_tag

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

Why nltk.pos_tag returns ***Fast*** once as an **Adverb** and another as an **Adjective** in the following examples?

```
nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize('fast fox'))
#returns
[('fast', 'RB'), ('fox', 'NN')]
```

and

```
nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize('fast money'))
#returns
[('fast', 'JJ'), ('money', 'NN')]
```

In both cases, it came before a noun. I noticed that it has a lot to do with ***Fast*** than the noun itself.

Here is another example that will return the expected results:

```
nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize('smart fox'))
#returns
[('smart', 'JJ'), ('fox', 'NN')]
```

and

```
nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize('smart money'))
#returns
[('smart ', 'JJ'), ('money', 'NN')]
```

I ran ***Fast*** followed by lots of names, and in **most cases**, it'll be returned as an RB (**Adverb**).